# Updating an MVC application Model along with data-source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

Firstly, new to Asp.Net MVC and ADO.NET entity data model.

While practicing an example, I created a table but forgot to set **"Identity specification**" to true for **PK**.

Created a model for MVC Application using entity data Model and worked fine.

Later on I've have set that **"Identity specification**" to true for that table in the DB.

When I try to insert a record an exception is raised and record does not get inserted.

> {"Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'Contacts'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

Here is the digner created class in the model, which should have changed as per schema changes in DB

```
public static Contact CreateContact(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string phone, string email)
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.Id = id;
            //
            return contact;
        }
```

There is no need for "Id" variable in the above Method Signature as but it is still auto generating that.

**How can we make our model to refresh itself or manually,
if the database schema is updated.**

**NOTE**: using C#, ASP.NET MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your DB schema correctly, then right-click your model and choose "Update Model from Database." This will correct the SSDL in your EDMX, which tells the EF that the `id` is store generated.

It will not, however, remove the `id` argument from the `CreateContact` method. The EF's code generator puts all non-nullable properties in the signature to this method. But once you have updated the SSDL, you should no longer get the exception when you save; if you want to use this method (you don't have to), you can just pass a 0.